# Difficulty understanding way of evaluating integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was trying to evaluate the definite integral

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 - \log_2(x) } .$$

The solution was just one line and read

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 - \log_2(x) } = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^k} = \log(2). $$

Both of these steps are entirely non-obvious for me and I have no idea how to justify them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not subing $2^y=x$ and use the geometric series?

Comment: Take the geometric series.  Integrate it.

Comment: Is the base of ur logx 2

Comment: @tired Could you possibly be more specific? When I do the substitution I get $\int_{-\infty}^0 \log(2) \frac{2^y}{1-y} dy$, but I don't see how to turn this into a geometric series to integrate.

Comment: @SimpleArt Could you possibly be more specific as to which geometric series?

Comment: @ShiksharthiSharma $\log_2$ has base $2$, $\log$ has base $e$.

Comment: Integrate this:$$1+r+r^2+\dots=\frac1{1-r}$$

Comment: @SimpleArt OK thank you! Now I understand the second step. Could you possibly also explain the first step (writing the integral as a sum)?

Comment: @SimpleArt $\log_2(x)\not\in(-1,1)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @Bye_World I do not get.  The expansion is fine here.

Comment: @SimpleArt Unless you're using the analytic continuation on the complex plane (and then I don't know if it's fine or not as my complex analysis is pretty weak), the geometric series converges to $\frac{1}{1-r}$ only if $|r|<1$.  In this case, with $\log_2(x)=r$, $\log_2(x)$ is not always in that range in the domain $x\in (0,1)$ (the domain of integration).

Comment: @Bye_World You don't get my hint then.

Comment: @Bye_World For this case, you end up setting $r=\frac{1}{2}$, so I believe it should be fine.

Comment: @SimpleArt Ah, you were explaining how to derive the second equality.  I was more interested in the first (because it seemed to be false) and thought that's what you were giving a hint for.  My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=1-\frac{\ln x}{\ln2}$, then $y=z\ln2$

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-\log_{2}x} dx &= 2\ln2 \int\limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z} \mathrm{e}^{-z\ln2} dz \\
&= 2\ln2 \int\limits_{\ln2}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-y}}{y} dy \\
&=-(2\ln2)\mathrm{Ei}(-\ln2) \approx 0.52495
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Ei}(z) = -\int\limits_{-z}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-t}}{t} dt
\end{equation}
is the [exponential integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Comment: :( t he answer is supposed to be $\ln(2)$?

Comment: Not according to Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F(1-log2(x))++from+x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+1

Comment: Well that is confusing...I got this problem from the 2014 MIT Integration Bee (http://math.mit.edu/~sswatson/pdfs/qualifying_round_2014.pdf), and none of their problems so far have involved $Ei(x)$. This solution makes sense to me though and obviously Wolfram Alpha rarely lies. Do you or @SimpleArt have any idea why the creator of the solution would have come up with the step to write the integral as a sum in the first place? (e.g. Could you point me to other integrals which can be evaluated by writing them as an infinite sum?)

Comment: @aras try the Maclaurin series of arctan.